# Cant align text to start Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

```
         
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "Name",
                        style: primaryTextStyle.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 18, fontWeight: semiBold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 8,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 18,
                  height: 18,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/tripple_dot.png')),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              "Rp. 10.000",
              style:
                  primaryTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: medium),
```

How to align the text to start? Ive wrap it with child column but it didnt work.

atm i think that flutter is more complicated than native when we are trying to positioning the layout, but when we are making a dynamic or interactive layout its better.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. add  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,` to first column

```
 Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Name",
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 18,
              height: 18,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/tripple_dot.png')),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Text(
          "Rp. 10.000",
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

to first column, it should work in some case if it didn't work. You can try text alight property from Text widget..

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot